# Vue3 ts script setup syntax, Vitest $setup.helperFunction is not a function

Tags: vuejs3, vitest, vue-script-setup

im trying to write tests with Vitest for my vue3 component

this is my component code:

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
import { reactive, computed,  ref, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { formatSubscribers } from '../../helpers/formatSubscribers'
import { formatDescription } from '../../helpers/formatDescription'
import { formatViews } from '../../helpers/formatViews'
import type {PropType} from 'vue'
import { useHistory } from '../../stores/history'
import type { IVideo } from '@/types/video'

const historyStore = useHistory()

interface State {
  readMore: boolean
}

const state = reactive<State>({
  readMore: false
})

const props = defineProps({
  videoId: { type: String, required: true },
  video: { type: Object as PropType<IVideo>, required: true }
})

const embedUrl = computed(
  () => `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${props.videoId}?autoplay=1&showinfo=1&mute=0`
)

const channelThumbnailUrl = computed(() => props.video?.channel?.thumbnail?.url)

const formattedSubscriberCount = computed(() => {
  const subscriberCount = props.video?.channel?.subscriberCount
  return formatSubscribers(subscriberCount) + ' inscritos'
})

const descriptionHtml = computed(() => {
  return formatDescription(props.video.description, state.readMore)
})

const readMoreButtonLabel = computed(() => {
  return state.readMore ? 'ver menos' : 'ver mais'
})

function toggleReadMore() {
  state.readMore = !state.readMore
}

function addVideo() {
  const history = historyStore.getHistory
  if (history.length === 0 || history[0].id !== props.video.id) {
    historyStore.addVideo(props.video)
  }
}

const videoPlayer = ref<HTMLIFrameElement | null>(null)
onMounted(() => {
  videoPlayer.value?.addEventListener('load', addVideo)
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="video">
    <div class="iframe-container">
      <iframe
        ref="videoPlayer"
        :src="embedUrl"
        frameborder="0"
        allowfullscreen
        v-if="video"
      ></iframe>
    </div>
    <h1 class="video__name">{{ video.title }}</h1>
    <div class="video__channel">
      <img :src="channelThumbnailUrl" :alt="video.channel.title" />
      <div>
        <p>{{ video.channel.title }}</p>
        <p>{{ formattedSubscriberCount }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="video__description">
      <p>{{ formatViews(video.viewCount) }}</p>
      <p v-html="descriptionHtml"></p>
      <button @click="toggleReadMore">{{ readMoreButtonLabel }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.iframe-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 56.25%;

  /* 16:9 Aspect Ratio (divide 9 by 16 = 0.5625) */
  iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.video {
  padding: 64px 0;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    padding: 128px 0;
  }

  &__name {
    margin-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }

  &__channel {
    display: flex;
    gap: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 14px;

    img {
      border-radius: 100%;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
    }
  }

  &__description {
    padding: 14px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    background-color: #282828;
    p:first-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 14px;
    }
    button {
      height: 48px;
      padding: 8px;
      margin-top: 14px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 8px;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: inherit;
      background-color: transparent;
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.08);
      border: 1px solid hsl(0, 0%, 18.82%);
      text-transform: capitalize;
      &:hover {
        background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.16);
      }
    }
  }
}
</style>
```

and this is my test:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import { describe, it,expect } from 'vitest'
import VideoPlayer from '@/components/UI/VideoPlayer.vue'
import type { IVideo } from '@/types/video';
import { formatViews } from '@/helpers/formatViews';

const videoMock: IVideo = {
  id: 'abc123',
  title: 'Test Video',
  description: 'This is a test video.',
  thumbnail: 'https://example.com/thumbnail.png',
  channel: {
    id: 'def456',
    title: 'Test Channel',
    thumbnail: {
      url: 'https://example.com/channel_thumbnail.png',
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    },
    subscriberCount: '1000',
  },
  viewCount: '100',
  duration: '1:00',
};

describe('Video', () => {
  it('displays the video title', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(VideoPlayer, { props: { video: videoMock, videoId: '1' } })
    expect(wrapper.find('.video__name').text()).toBe('Test Video')
  })

  it('displays the channel title and subscriber count', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(VideoPlayer, { props: { video: videoMock, videoId: '1' } })
    expect(wrapper.find('.video__channel p:first-child').text()).toBe('Test Channel')
    expect(wrapper.find('.video__channel p:last-child').text()).toBe('1,000')
  })

})
```

the error that i got:

TypeError: $setup.formatViews is not a function

❯ Proxy._sfc_render src/components/UI/VideoPlayer.vue:81:13

I don't know if I need to mock $setup.formatViews. this is the problem? how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the implementation of `formatSubscribers`, made a computed property using the function, maybe it worked as I'm not getting this error anymore, I just need to finish the test

Comment: yes that really worked, I don't know if there is another way